# What does "AL lib: alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed" mean?

Tags: java, swing, libgdx

I'm trying to engage myself into the Libgdx OpenGL framework. I've used `LwjglApplication` for creating some simple apps that render boxes, some meshes and some textures. I came across Aurelien Ribon's app that creates rigid Box2D bodies. He used the `LwjglCanvas` to integrate with Java's Swing. I tried making one myself, I created a `JFrame` then added the `LwjglCanvas`. Then set the `JFrame`'s default operation on close to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

However everytime I close the application, this logs to my console:

`AL lib: alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed`.

I don't know what it means and it's not doing me any harm. I just want to know what it means. According to `LwjglCanvas` docs:

`All OpenGL calls are done on the EDT. This is slightly less efficient then a dedicated thread, but greatly simplifies synchronization. Note that you may need to call stop() or a Swing application may deadlock on System.exit due to how LWJGL and/or Swing deal with shutdown hooks.`

Where should I bind the `LwjglCanvas.stop()`, should I add it to the `EventDispatchThread` queue or should I bind it to the `JFrame.addWindowListener`?

And what does "AL lib: alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed" really mean?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The AL lib is the "audio library" used by Libgdx (one of the OpenAL variants).

I believe this message just means that the audio library is cleaning up some (in your case just one) audio streams/handles for you.  If you see this at exit, its harmless as all resources will be cleaned up by the OS.

If you internally cleanup your audio before exiting, the message should go away.

For more details, look for `alc_cleanup` in here:
http://repo.or.cz/w/openal-soft.git/blob/HEAD:/Alc/ALc.c

Comment: I see. So the message have nothing to do with the event dispatch thread in Java Swing. How come the message is not present when closing the LibgdxApplication?

Comment: Perhaps `alc_cleanup` isn't invoked in some app exit paths (e.g., if `System.exit()` is invoked, `alc_cleanup` will not get invoked.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and for the code reference. It really cleared things for me.

Answer (score 12):

`AL.destroy();` must be called before the application shuts down. this call is normally included in a finally block, but if the application calls `System.exit(0)`, finally blocks are no longer executed.

Comment: In my case it was a System.exit(0) that lead to this error.

Answer (score 8):

You should try always closing your app with the piece of code below:

```
Gdx.app.exit();
```

I usually put it in my **pause()** method, because there was no reason for my app to run in the background.

This static method tells the framework that your application is planning on closing and will thus release all resources effectively. The error you're getting is because the JNI interface has loaded an OpenAL library, but the System is closed before that library is properly unloaded and released. I had the same problem as you did, but this solved it. As stated in the JavaDoc, the exit() method:

> Schedule[s] an exit from the application. On android, this will cause a call to **pause()** and **dispose()** some time in the future, it will not immediately finish your application.