# When I create a stack strcuct variable in jni part and send it by value to native, junk is sent

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

When I create an in stack variable from a struct in jni cpp and send it to a function in cpp, junk data is sent in the struct.

The strange thing is that if I print some data from the struct before sending it, the program runs correctly

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_dev_eng_gdx_database_DbSquirrel_jniSetBodyLayer(JNIEnv* env, jobject object, jlong address, jshort id, jfloat zDisplacement, jboolean useVecFriction, jfloat friction, jfloat frictionX, jfloat frictionY, jboolean useSlopePhysics, jboolean useSlopeRotation, jboolean rollOnMove, jboolean useVecRoll, jfloat roll, jfloat rollX, jfloat rollY) {

        BodyLayer bodyLayer = {.zDisplacement = zDisplacement, .useVecFriction = useVecFriction, .friction = friction, .vecFriction = {frictionX, frictionY},
                                .useSlopePhysics = useSlopePhysics, .useSlopeRotation = useSlopeRotation,
                                .rollOnMove = rollOnMove, .useVecRoll = useVecRoll, .roll = roll, .vecRoll = {rollX, rollY} };

        //std::cout << "useVecFriction " << bodyLayer.useVecFriction << "\n";
        //std::cout << "friction " << friction << "\n";
        ((SquirrelDb*)address)->setBodyLayer(toC2(id), bodyLayer);


}
```

If I run the code printing the struct data whith std::cout, the program runs correctly.

If I run the code without printing the struct data it throws this error:

```
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

Thanks ind advance

Comment: That error message seems to be a symptom of the system exiting, and not an explanation of the cause. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161714/what-does-al-lib-alc-cleanup-1-device-not-closed-mean

Comment: I agree, inside the setBodyLayer() function, I store the data, I'm passing by value, so a copy should be made. later in the program when that copy is used it throws the error.
As I state earlier, if I print the data it works fine, if I don't print it it fails

Comment: Do you know at what point in `SetBodyLayer()` the exit happens? I would think we need to see that code.

Comment: After doing a lot of debugging it seems that I was saving a pointer to a pointer instead of a pointer in java to be used through jni, so it was a memory issue. Thanks